# How invoking lambda function from cloud front without passing by apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, invoke

Actually, I invoke a lambda function by url that pass by apigateway.
I have an import function that take more than 30 seconds so in this case the apigateway return cancelled.
My question is there are methods to invoke the lambda without passing by apigateway?

Comment: Like [Lambda Function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html)? Also, have you already rejected Lambda@Edge?